# Installing sdist in venv: cannot install packages from install_requires

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm trying to convert a single file Python script into a package with a CLI script. I'm following the [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) guide.

I wanted to use `venv` to try out my locally built `sdist`, but I seem to be getting errors from `pip install` in the virtual environment.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$ python3 setup.py sdist
$ cd ~/venv
$ python3 -m venv .
$ source bin/activate
$ pip3 install ~/my_module/dist/my_module_0.1.tar.gz

Processing ~/my_module/dist/my_module-0.1.tar.gz
Collecting PIL (from my_module==0.1)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from my_module==0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL (from my_module==0.1)
```

My package structure (in case that matters):

```
├── my_module
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module.py
└── setup.py
```

### setup.py

Note `install_requires`.

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='my_module',
    # ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-cli=my_module.cli:main',
            'my-app=my_module.app:main'
        ],
    },
    install_requires=[
        'PIL',
        'imagehash',
        'exifread'
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6'
```

### my_module.py

Excerpt to show dependencies...

```
import os
import sys
import time
import shutil
import json
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError, cpu_count
from PIL import Image
import imagehash
import exifread

# ...
```

No matter what I put in my setup.py `install_requires` list, the `virtualenv` `pip3` doesn't seem to be able to find it. My impression was that it should go and install these requirements in the virtual environment.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here. Is there something wrong with my package setup, or my testing methodology?

Comment: I thought there is no `PIL` module anymore. Try `pillow`?

Comment: LOL. This is why I shouldn't code on weekends. You can post this as an answer, as it happens to be the solution here.

Comment: Also, I tried putting `os` into the `install_requires` list, just to see if it was just `PIL` which was wrong. Obviously that didn't work either....

Comment: `os` is a built-in module, you can only install things on the `PyPi`, doubtlessly a built-in module is not on `PyPi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @Sraw in the comments.

`PIL` is a typo. It should be `Pillow`.

I had considered it could be something like that, so I tried putting something I thought would never fail, like `os`, but that also fails since it’s not hosted in the repository since it’s a core package distributed with Python itself.

Hopefully this helps some lost soul in the future who forgets that you `import PIL` but `pip install Pillow`.